# how can i refer WCF client config settings from the exe which doesnt have a config file

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I have a WCF Service and Client(dll) application. This client dll is loaded by a myexe.exe but this(myexe.exe) doesn't have myexe.exe.config file. so now how to refer my client config settings from the exe which doesnt have a config file.

Comment: If you can't/won't use a config file for the exe (which is the usual way), you have two options:  1. Have the client DLL read a file for it's configuration data or 2. Do the configuration of the client in the DLL code.  Either of those options, however, will defeat the purpose of having a DLL, as it will lose at least some degree of the reusability of libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Then add a `myexe.exe.config` file.

Comment: i dont have the code for that exe but my WCF client dll has its config  and i should not create a config file for that myexe.exe please suggest me with another options.

Comment: if you create myexe.exe.config and reference Client(dll) in myexe.exe then code inside Client(dll) is able to read entries from myexe.exe.config

Comment: I am currently implementing the solution as you said but i wanted to know any other alternatives which provide solution without creating exe.config.